# Is $\phi(x) = x + \frac{1}{x}$ a contraction?

Tags: real-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

Given the metric space $M := ([1, \infty), |.|)$, is the function $\phi(x) = x + \frac{1}{x}$ a contraction? I know the answer must be "no" because then $\phi$ should have a fixed point by the Banach fixed point theorem and it clearly doesn't have one.

But isn't it true that:

$$\left| \frac{\phi(x_2) - \phi(x_1)}{x_2 - x_2} \right| = \left| 1 - \frac{1}{x_1 x_2} \right| < 1$$

implying that $\phi$ is a contraction after all? Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Isn't the golden ratio a fixed point though?

Comment: You didn't mean $\phi(x)=x+1/x$ as contraction, I suppose? See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3345079/prove-that-fx-x1-x-is-a-contraction-but-not-a-strong-one-on-1-infty).

Comment: You have $\left\vert \frac{\phi(x_2) - \phi(x_1)}{x_2 - x_2} \right\vert =\frac{1}{x_1 x_2} $ not $\left| \frac{\phi(x_2) - \phi(x_1)}{x_2 - x_2} \right| = \left| 1 - \frac{1}{x_1 x_2} \right|$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: Yes, that was a typo, I guess this is a duplicate then.

Comment: Banach fixed point theorem is not applicable here since the metric space is not complete.

Comment: $[1, \inf )$ not complete?

Comment: Banach thm not applicable since function isn't a contraction, as the answer points out. So iteration sequence would not be Cauchy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The definition of a [contracting map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_mapping) $\Phi$ is that it exists $0 \le k \lt 1$ such that

$$\Vert \Phi(x) - \Phi(y) \Vert \le k \Vert x- y \Vert$$ for any $x,y$ not that

$$\Vert \Phi(x) - \Phi(y) \Vert \lt \Vert x- y \Vert$$ for any $x,y$.

Your $\phi$ is not a contracting map as

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 1} \left\vert \frac{\phi(x) - \phi(1)}{x - 1} \right\vert = 1$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\left| \frac{\phi(x_2) - \phi(x_1)}{x_2 - x_2} \right| = \left|  \frac{1}{x_1 x_2} \right| \le 1$$ but this does not say that $\phi$ is a contraction. For $\phi$ to be a contraction there must exist a number $c \in (0,1)$ (independent of $x_1,x_2$) such that $ | {\phi(x_2) - \phi(x_1)}| \le c|x_1-x_2|$ for all $x_1,x_2$  and there is no such $c$ as seen by taking $x_1=1,x_2=1+\frac 1 n$ and letting $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

A contraction is a function for which a fixed number $C\in(0,1)$ exists such that $\vert f(x_2)-f(x_1)\vert\leq C\vert x_2-x_1\vert$. You showed that $\vert \phi(x_2)-\phi(x_1)\vert\leq\vert x_2-x_1\vert=1\cdot\vert x_2-x_1\vert$. You're basically claiming $C=1$, but $C$ needs to be smaller than 1. Basically, the difference quotient of a contraction needs to be bounded not by 1, but by a number *smaller* than 1. Which is not the case here.

But there's a fixed point anyway: $\phi(1)=2>1$, but $\phi(2)=\frac32<2$, so by the intermediate value theorem, a fixed point exists. As pointed out in the comments, it's the golden ratio, the solution of $1+\frac1x=x$, which can be transformed to $x^2-x-1=0$, the solutions of which can be explicitly calculated. One of them is in $[1,\infty)$.